# how are number formats and character sets utilized by java?

Tags: java, encoding, number-formatting

binary, decimal, octal and hexadecimal are number systems/number formats. 
ASCII, unicode (UTF8, UTF16 etc) are charecter sets.

how does java translate user input?
to which default number format?
and to which default charecter set/encoding standard?

Answer (score 0):

> to which default number format?

User input would be strings thus it would be up to the developer to get the numbers from the text, e.g. by using `Scanner.nextInt()`. How such a number would be interpreted would depend on the representation of that number but when in doubt, assume Java will read the number as an integer.

> and to which default charecter set/encoding standard?

AFAIK that would depend on the JVM default enconding which defaults to the system enconding, unless the developper defines an encoding. Note that depending on the source of input there might be some api/library specific settings.

Comment: when you say system.. is it the operating system?

Comment: @DJR yes the os but the default encoding might also be overridden by a system property passed to the jvm.